# Facebook client-side authentication -> retrieving user info from our own database

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm building a webapp and I'm planning on allowing users to login using Facebook. I understand the client-side login process, but I'm not sure how I would go and retrieve the user's data from my own database.

Once the client has authenticated using Facebook I can retrieve the user's /me graph node and use the userID to authenticate against my database, but that would be a huge security hole.

The other solution I thought of would be to pass the access token to the server and use that to retrieve the user's data server-side, but I believe I read somewhere that this is not acceptable behaviour.

What would be the right way to inform the server that an, and which user is authenticated?

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Would users only be able to log in using Facebook, or would it be an option to link an existing account?

Comment: It would be an option to link to an existing account.

Comment: Ah, found the solution myself.

The signed_request can be sent to the server and allows for secure authentication since it's encrypted using the secret_id as a key.

Source:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518905/verifying-facebook-users-server-side?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found the solution myself. The signed_request can be sent to the server and allows for secure authentication since it's encrypted using secret_id as the key.

Source: [Verifying Facebook users server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518905/verifying-facebook-users-server-side?rq=1)